# redirecting standard output to print messages in gui instead of terminal

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx
import os
import sys

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(480, 400))
        self.panel = MyPanel(self, -1)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)
        setstd()
        print 'test'
        """
        syncall()
        """

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '', (40, 60))

class MyText():
    def write(string):
        label = frame.panel.text.GetLabel()
        frame.panel.text.SetLabel(string)

def setstd():
    sys.stdout = MyText()
    sys.stderr = MyText()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'DropBox log')
app.MainLoop()
```

Without print 'test', it even runs, but with print 'test', it doesn't run nor redirect output.

How to redirect standard output to print messages in gui instead of terminal?

Comment: Please fix your indentation for setstd().  I'm pretty sure I know what you mean, but indentation is kind of important in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t515815-wxpython-redirect-the-stdout-to-a-textctrl.html

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `print` statement with wxPython, where it ends up depends on how you called `wx.App()`.

`wx.App(redirect=False)` or simply `wx.App(0)` will send print statements to a console window, otherwise they will be sent to a little textbox window.